# Confusing error in R: Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings, : line 1 did not have 42 elements)

Tags: r

I am new to R. I am trying to read in a "CSV" file that is space-space delimited. The file does not have headers. It looks like this

```
Element1 Element2
Element5 Element6 Element7
```

I am trying to read it in like this:

```
> mydata <- read.table("/PathTo/file.csv")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 14 elements
```

Why does it expect 14 elements in the first row? How do I import this file?

Comment: @SimonO101 if you put that as an answer I will accept

Comment: Your data is not in the table format, why use read.table?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`read.table` wants to return a `data.frame`, which must have an element in each column. Therefore R expects each row to have the same number of elements and it doesn't fill in empty spaces by default. Try `read.table("/PathTo/file.csv" , fill = TRUE )` to fill in the blanks.

e.g.

```
read.table( text= "Element1 Element2
Element5 Element6 Element7" , fill = TRUE , header = FALSE )
#        V1       V2       V3
#1 Element1 Element2         
#2 Element5 Element6 Element7
```

A note on whether or not to set `header = FALSE`... `read.table` tries to automatically determine if you have a header row thus:

> `header` is set to `TRUE` if and only if the first row contains one fewer field than the number of columns

Comment: +1, but I think you meant to uncomment that second line and I think you meant to add `header = FALSE` considering your sample data, right?

Comment: @AnandaMahto `header=FALSE` is the default, and yes, shouldn't be an octothorpe in that! Not sure how that ended up there!! EDIT: So given the data you are of course (as usual) right

Comment: I fixed the same issue just using `read.delim()` instead of `read.table()`.

Answer (score 3):

To read characters try

```
scan("/PathTo/file.csv", "")
```

If you're reading numeric values, then just use

```
scan("/PathTo/file.csv")
```

`scan` by default will use *white space* as separator. The type of the second arg defines 'what' to read (defaults to double()).